# Am I following the BEM method correctly?

Tags: html, css, bem

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
        <div class="site-footer__form-container widget-area">
            <div id="footer-sidebar1">
                <?php if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
                            dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
                        }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-footer__nav-container">

                <div class="site-footer__events">
                    <h3 class="site-footer__title">Events</h3>
                    <ul class="site-footer__nav-list">
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">Parade Of Lights</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">SeaFair</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">Burials At Sea</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="site-footer__about">
                    <h3 class="site-footer__title">About us</h3>
                    <ul class="site-footer__nav-list">
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./owners" class="site-footer__link">Owners</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./blog" class="site-footer__link">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="site-footer__contact">
                    <h3 class="site-footer__title">Weddings</h3>
                    <ul class="site-footer__nav-list">
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./wedding-info" class="site-footer__link">Wedding Info</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="site-footer__list-item">
                            <a href="./wedding-menus" class="site-footer__link">Wedding Menus</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="site-footer__contact-container">
            <p class="site-footer__phone">(206) 123-4567</p>
            <p class="site-footer__address">
                <a href="#" class="site-footer__link">1234 Water St. Seattle, WA 98107</a>
            </p>
            <div class="site-footer__icons-container">
                <div class="site-footer__facebook"></div>
                <div class="site-footer__instagram"></div>
                <div class="site-footer__twitter"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-footer__copyright-container">
            <p class="site-footer__copywrite">Copyright © 2017 Friendship Charters. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Here I am trying to write the HTML for a footer of a website, and I am wondering if I am correctly following the BEM methodology/style guide. It's pretty confusing to me. I'm never sure if I should create more 'blocks' or not. Would this be correct? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It's totally OK, may be not perfect (I'm not so cool in BEM), but it looks OK

Comment: If you are having trouble using a tool or methodology, it's not always your fault--it could be that of the tool or methodology. Many people are confused by BEM. Even if implemented correctly it's horribly verbose. That, coupled with the fact that recent trends including CSS scoping have reduced the need for something like BEM, are why you hear so little about it recently--very few people are using it. You should think carefully about whether you really want to commit to BEM.

Comment: @torazaburo _"CSS scoping"_ like [the obsolete `:scope` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Paleo Haha. No, I meant CSS scoping like CSS modules, or CSS scoping as found in frameworks such as Angular.

Comment: @Quentin The BEM methodology is always considered as _opinion based_. This is not only a syntax but also a method of reusing CSS classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is OK for the BEM syntax. But monolithic, too semantic, and nothing is reusable. I suggest to use the following hierarchy of blocks:

- site-footer

  - widget-area
  - multi-columns

    - titled-list (events)
    - titled-list (about)
    - titled-list (contact)
  - contact-box

    - icon (facebook)
    - icon (instagram)
    - icon (twitter)

The HTML code:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
    <div class="site-footer__form-container widget-area">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="site-footer__nav-container multi-columns">
            <div class="multi-columns__col titled-list">
                <h3 class="titled-list__title">Events</h3>
                <ul class="titled-list__ul">
                    <li class="titled-list-li">
                        <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">Parade Of Lights</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="titled-list-li">
                        <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">SeaFair</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="titled-list-li">
                        <a href="./special-events" class="site-footer__link">Burials At Sea</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="multi-columns__col titled-list">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="multi-columns__col titled-list">
                ...
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-footer__contact-container contact-box">
        <p class="contact-box__phone">(206) 123-4567</p>
        <p class="contact-box__address">
            <a href="#" class="contact-box__link">1234 Water St. Seattle, WA 98107</a>
        </p>
        <div class="contact-box__icons-container">
            <div class="icon icon--facebook"></div>
            <div class="icon icon--instagram"></div>
            <div class="icon icon--twitter"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-footer__copyright-container">
        <p class="site-footer__copywrite">Copyright © 2017 Friendship Charters. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Each *block* is a **context**. Each *element* is related to its block context. That means a block is not aware where it is positioned. Only elements can be positioned, related to the parent block. In your example, the elements `.site-footer__form-container`, `.site-footer__nav-container`, etc. are responsible for positioning the child blocks `.widget-area`, `.multi-columns`, etc. inside the parent block `.site-footer`.

If a pattern is repeated, remember to reuse the same blocks (`.icon`) or elements (`.multi-columns__col`) and add modifiers for possible differences.

Always think how to make your CSS classes reusable in the rest of the Web page (maybe you could use `.multi-columns` or `.icon` elsewhere?).

If something could be a block but is small and not reusable elsewhere (the copyright container), then you can keep it as an element in the parent block just because it is simpler.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Good Job @Paleo. We at Storyblok follow the BEM in quite everything we do - so for you )ChewyMcFats) I would recommend you to follow the explanation. No need for me to answer again.

Comment: @Paleo Thank you! that explains things much more, makes a lot of sense! :3